# How to force exact scale on ipad

Tags: html, ipad, viewport

What I'm trying to achieve is: to force scale **1.0** when ipad is in landscape mode, and **0.75** when it's in portrait, but with **disabled user scaling**. I tried all combinations of meta viewport tag, and nothing worked:

- when *user-scalable* is **no**, landscape works fine, but it doesn't scale to 0.75 in portrait, no matter how I set *maximum* and *minimum* scale
- when *user-scalable* is **yes**, it works fine sometimes, but since there is lot of adding content with ajax, sometimes when page gets longer, the page just scales down to fit whole page on screen, and I want to prevent that

So, is there a way to force scaling to exact number? Or disable scaling when page length changes? (Page width should always be 1024px, no different css for different orientation and no width=device-width, I just need scaling)

Answer (score 6):

Patrick's answer is def useful, here is a more tested version

```
var checkOrientation;
checkOrientation = function() {
  var viewport;
  viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
  if (window.orientation === 90 || window.orientation === -90) {
    return viewport.setAttribute("content", "width:device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1");
  } else {
    return viewport.setAttribute("content", "width:device-width, initial-scale=0.6, user-scalable=1");
  }
};
window.onorientationchange = function() {
  return checkOrientation();
};
checkOrientation();
```

And don't forget to put this in your document's head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Note that, one of the difference, is the commas instead of semi-colons in the arguments

Comment: Actually omitting the meta tag in the head, while using the script, seems to have solved some problems for me. I can't really say that I understand though. Seems the static tag competed with the javascript somehow.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to achieve this solely with a meta viewport setting.

It is however possible to detect the orientation with javascript, and possible to change the meta viewport-setting with javascript, so you can have a script trigger on orientation-change and setting a different viewport.

Perhaps something like this (not tested):

```
window.onorientationchange = function() {
  viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
  if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) {
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; user-scalable=1');            
  } else {
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width; initial-scale=0.75; user-scalable=0');            
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to put the maximum-scale=1 in the javascript as well, and to use the correct "width=device-width":

```
var checkOrientation;
checkOrientation = function() {
  var viewport;
  viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
  if (window.orientation === 90 || window.orientation === -90) {
    return viewport.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=1");
  } else {
    return viewport.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=0.6, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=1");
  }
};
window.onorientationchange = function() {
  return checkOrientation();
};
checkOrientation();
```

Answer (score -1):

Or use your server side language to detect the presence of iPad via the USER_AGENT.

Comment: This is a snippit... your answer may have merit but please explain how you'd use the USER_AGENT string to produce what the OP is asking.